# How to make an extension method on an enumeration type still applicable even though the enum object is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

**Scenario:**

The `Create` action method will pass an uninitialized instance of `Person` to the `View`.
The `View` will show a dropdown control with "--Select--" highlighted.
Since the property `Sex` is nullable, I cannot invoke the extension method.

How to fix this problem?

**Model:**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public enum Sex { Male, Female };
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select either Female or Male.")]
        public Sex? Sex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var p = new Person();
        ViewBag.SelectList = p.Sex.Value.GetSelectList();//Source of error!
        return View(p);
    }
```

**Partial View:**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Person
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sex, ViewBag.SelectList as SelectList,"--Select--")
</div>
```

**Extension:**

```
 public static class Utilities
    {
        public static SelectList GetSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum obj)
        {
            var values = from TEnum x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                         select new { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x };
            return new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text", obj);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you make your extension method to accept a `Nullable` as a parameter? (This extension method looks like a code smell to me)

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static object GetSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum? obj)
        where TEnum : struct 
    {
        var values = from TEnum x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                     select new { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x };
        return new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text", obj);
    }
}
```

and use without extracting value:

```
ViewBag.SelectList = p.Sex.GetSelectList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Why does it look like a code smell to you?

Comment: @Stack, it doesn't look straightforward to me. What I expect to see here is two parts - first creates a list of available values, second - selects the current value. Your approach is different - you're creating list of values together with selecting something in this list (as far as I got it). Maybe it is just a problem of my understanding of ASP.Net MVC - I do not really know much about it.

Comment: Is it possible to create a single extension method that is applicable for both enum and nullable enum?

Comment: @Stack, I believe no - that's why we have an `overloading`